# Is there any way to get the string that is lost?

Tags: java, string

I have created one string

```
String str="ashish";
```

Now the `str` is assigned another String literal.

```
str="mehara"
```

Now is there any way so that we get the value `"ashish"` that is already lost? If not then what will happen to this lost String literal `"ashish"`?

Comment: you should never need this. just store everything that still might be useful another variable/object/file/continuum of time

Comment: I don't think the question deserves so many down votes considering the OP is new here at SO and the question was not that bad.

Answer (score 3):

> *Now is there any way so that we get the value "ashish" that is already lost?*

How would you do that? How would you specify which "lost" string you want to retrieve? If you say give me the old "ashish" string, then you already know it is "ashish", and so it was never lost:

```
 String str = "ashish";
 str = "mehara";
 str = "ashish";
```

If you simply want to store the previous value, you have to write the code to do that:

```
 String str = "ashish";
 String previous = str;
 str = "mehara";
 str = previous;
```

> *If not then what will happen to this lost String literal "ashish"?*

Nothing necessarily happens to it, it is just no longer accessible to you. Java's string literals are stored in a [string pool](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20string%20pool), which is in the *runtime constant pool*, which the [JVM specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.4) states doesn't necessarily have to be garbage collected.

However, garbage collected or not, from your point of view it does not matter what happens to it. You simply don't have access to it any more if you drop all references to it. It's like meeting somebody at a bar and writing their phone number down on a napkin, then losing the napkin. The person probably still exists, but you aren't going to be able to call them (bummer). The solution is to not lose the napkin, or to memorize their phone number first.

Answer (score 1):

No, that string gets lost in the oblivion, mixed with all the other 1's and 0's floating around inside the computer. aka it eventually gets garbage collected and can no longer be accessed.

Comment: Actually, it's not. Since "ashish" is a String literal, it is still in the String pool, and doing `str="ashish"` will reassign the same String instance to `str` again.

Comment: @JBNizet : Is there any way to regain the value from the String pool ?

Comment: @JB but you still have to assign it directly. When doing user input or randomly generating strings, this may not be possible.

Comment: String literals aren't necessarily garbage collected. They are stored in the runtime constant pool, and the [JVM spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.4) (2.5.5 and 2.5.4) specifically states that this area need not be garbage collected.

Comment: But can you get info out of it?

Comment: @DonyorM Get what info out of what?

Comment: @JasonC the JVM spec. That's the question

Comment: @DonyorM You can get all the info you want out of the [JVM specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/index.html); it is a free and publicly available document.